# can't loading image in Gluon javafx

Tags: javafx, gluon

I have a problem while trying to add image in my scene in the javafx gluon application using the line bellow 
I put the img.jpg file in the pin folder

```
Imageview image = new ImageView(new Image("file: img.jpg"));
```

and also using ("/img.jpg")
any suggestions ?

Comment: sorry I forget to close the double quotation in the question 
 " file: img.jpg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image should be stored under `src/main/resources` folder according to a Gradle project structure. Usually it should be under the same package as your class, in this case the following code will load the image:

```
Image image = new Image(YourClass.class.getResource("img.jpg").toExternalForm());
ImageView imageView  = new ImageView(image);
```

More information about loading resources in Java can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Comment: When reading a serialized file with ObjectInputStream I had to provide path to that folder like this: "src/main/resources/" + fileName.